# How can I get a true random from an array? Or should I do something else entirely?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display a different madlib each time a user clicks the submit button. Only needs to be clicked 3 times. I am using the functions below, but it doesn't seem all that random. I also have a snippet of the dogLib function that creates three madlibs and then calls the function above it to generate a random madlib string.

```js
//Class: madlibGenerator.js



//----- Private Helper Functions -----

//Get Random: word strings for randam madlib 
//Get Random: madlib string to display
function getRandomString(array) {
  for(var i = array.length - 1; i>0; i--){
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return this.word = array.pop();
}


//Set: set user input word string arrays into the getRandomString(array) 
//Get: a final array of words to add to the madLib display strings
function getFinalWordArray(){
  var prpN = getRandomString(this.properNouns);
  var adjt = getRandomString(this.adjectives);
  var noun = getRandomString(this.nouns);
  var vrb = getRandomString(this.verbs);

  return finalWordArray = [prpN, adjt, noun, vrb];
}


//Get Random Dog Lib 
function getDogLib() {
  //Get Random Dog Words
  var dogWordsArray = getFinalWordArray();

  //DogLibs
  var dogLibOne = 
      "What is that " + dogWordsArray[1] +
      " sound!" +
      " Hey! " + dogWordsArray[0] +
      "!  You come " + dogWordsArray[3] +
      " you crazy " + dogWordsArray[2] + 
      "!";

  var dogLibTwo = 
      dogWordsArray[0] + "!! " + 
      dogWordsArray[0] + "!! " +
      "Come " + dogWordsArray[3] +
      " and lay on my clean " + dogWordsArray[2] + 
      " while your treat is still " + dogWordsArray[1] + "!";

  var dogLibThree = 
      "My human comes home and takes me for a " + dogWordsArray[3] + 
      " where I sit on a " + dogWordsArray[2] + 
      " and get my " + dogWordsArray[1] +
      " belly rubbed!";

  //Make array of DogLibs
  var dogLibArray = [dogLibOne, dogLibTwo, dogLibThree];

  //Pick random dogLib string to display 
  finalDogLib = getRandomString(dogLibArray);
}

//Display: Random MadLib to console for now
function displayMadlib(pDisplayIDValue) {
  if(pDisplayIDValue == "dogLib"){
    //display
    getDogLib();
    console.log(finalDogLib);    
  }else if(pDisplayIDValue == "loveLib"){
    //display
    getLoveLib();
    console.log(finalLoveLib);
  }else if(pDisplayIDValue == "funnyLib"){
    //display
    getFunnyLib();
    console.log(finalFunnyLib);
  }
}
```

The code above isn't broken, it just doesn't produce a true random.

//Preferred Result: the program displays a different madlib each time the user clicks the submit button. The user only needs to click the button 3 times to get different madlibs, the fourth click clears the form and starts the program fresh.

Thank you!

I am open to any idea to make this a truly random madlibGenerator. Maybe counting number of clicks from a submit button?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @lealceldeiro Please don't be so rude. There is nothing to reproduce, I am asking for a better way to do something.

Comment: Nothing rude here. Just a suggestion that will help us help you

Comment: @mplungjan Well why don't you read the code and suggest a better way to ask my question, because I am new to this, I am a student and there is nothing to reproduce.

Comment: There certainly is. You need to click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58204055/edit) and then `[<>]` [stack-snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and then produce the smallest runnable example that shows the issue with relevant HTML, CSS,  input and expected output

Comment: @mplungjan I can give you my console output if you like. Maybe that would help with getting a better solution.

Comment: Can't you post the actual form and such?

Comment: Also it is confusing when you say _Example of dogLib generator function:_  - is that the actual code you are using?

Comment: I think rather than picking a random item from an array x times (and having the risk of selecting the same item a few times) you want to shuffle an array randomly and then read it from the top.

Comment: @James Hmm, I thought I was shuffeling it randomly,  in the getRandomString function in the madlibGenerator class. Is that not what it is doing? Could that be better?

Comment: @James I was trying to give you a vote for your comment, but I deleted it by accident and it won't let me correct my error. But you got my vote, the guy above got it because he actually started giving me suggestions.

Comment: To all, I have read the forms, I did my best to ask the question clearly and concisely, some did not agree and others answered my question. Thank you for all your input, I will take it into consideration for the future.

Comment: Your question looked daunting, there was a lot of code and as such people suggested you cut it down to a "Minimal" example, which is one of the aspects of a "Good" question on Stackoverflow. There wasn't anything inherently rude in doing that (as others have stated), but just something to be aware of. Anyway, this question might be better received on Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com, as they are specifically for "Is there a better way to do X" questions, while Stackoverflow is more for "How do I fix Y". Also, in your example, you had a couple "Your"s that should be "You're"s :)

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you for the codereview.stackexchange.com, I did not know that existed, next time. Look, I get that there is a lot to weed through, but no one is perfect, some are new, some have kids yelling in the background, three generations under one roof, two jobs and are students full time.

Comment: @TimLewis  The people asking questions are just as valuable as the people answering the questions. It comes off as rude to a person who  is trying their best to do what is expected of them, in every role they play throughout the day. Assuming someone hasn't read the documents here on stackoverflow and then  telling them to read it is rude. It makes the person asking the question feel small.

Comment: @TimLewis Minimal and Reproducible is hard for someone who is learning a new language, literally, a new language in asking questions about computer languages. Maybe my heading should say, ""Student I will get better at this! Promise!!" :)

Comment: Yeah, I would avoid that title; it definitely wouldn't help. Also, its impossible for us to know your personal situation from you asking a question here on Stackoverflow, but I'm also not sure what any of that has to do with anything. *"Assuming someone hasn't read the documents here on Stackoverflow and then telling them to read it is rude"* - I disagree; that documentation exists for a reason, and that is to be read to better understand how to use Stackoverflow. It's expected of all of us, we've all done it. Anyway, best of luck in everything, keep asking and learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So *true* randomness is going to be tough to achieve. Math.Random() from the javascript library isn't truly random as you've guessed, it's pseudo-random, meaning there is a pattern to it over a large number of inputs. Computers inherently can't really do true randomness, because they are always going to have to take some number, perform some sort of algorithm on it (these are usually "Mersenne Twisters" - fun wikipedia read), and spit out the result.

That said, I don't know exactly how to improve on what you've put into place here. With PRNG, a really large number of possible inputs can help a lot. If you want absolutely true randomness, the easiest way would probably be to hook into random.org's API (https://api.random.org/dashboard - developer license is free, limited to 1000 requests per day). Hooking into an API might be more work than you were planning on, but random.org uses (if I remember right) atmospheric noise and barometric pressure from the Earth to create their random numbers, so it's about as close to true randomness as you can possibly get.

I hope this helps!

Comment: idk, I read the question more as "pick x different items semi-randomly from an array" and less about "the math.random function in javascript isn't random enough" but ok, this is the accepted answer.

Comment: It did, and I didn't have to change to the edited question above to get your answer. Thank you!! I will read the article you gave and look into the API, because API's are always cool!! Unless they use thousands of lines of code to implement. I also was coming to the conclusion that I did not have enough input. :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped. I read through all of your code and I think what you're doing is really the best you can do with Math.Random(), and adding more inputs probably will help a lot. I've never used their API, I just know a lot of folks use it so I assume it's not too insane :)